# Flask request context and celery

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, celery, flask-session

So, I am developing a multi-tenant Flask application. I am currently using sqlalchemy and the multi-schema pattern. 
To define the current schema I use this function:

```
def on_pool_checkout(dbapi_conn, connection_rec, connection_proxy):

    cursor = dbapi_conn.cursor()

    if 'tenant' in session:
        query = "SET search_path TO {}, public;".format(session['tenant'])
        print(query)
        cursor.execute(query)
        dbapi_conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        return

    cursor.execute("SET search_path TO public;")
    print('SCHEMA PUBLIC')
    dbapi_conn.commit()
    cursor.close()

event.listen(Pool, 'checkout', on_pool_checkout)
```

It works great when I have a request context but, when a celery task tries to use a connection I get an error saying that I am not working in a request context.

Is there a way to access the session in a celery task or a different way to share the tenant with my connection event?

Comment: Why can't you just pass all what you need through function arguments and remove a session use completely?

Comment: How would I accomplish that? I need the tenant argument to change at runtime depending on the client who is trying to connect. If I pass it as an argument to the event listener it would not be dynamic.